# controller store function array laravel 5.5

Tags: arrays, laravel, function, controller, store

I need some help. I have a problem with store function with array in laravel. When I submit my form, I got error massage that "ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given".

This is my store function :

```
public function store(request $request) {

$input=$request->all();
$images=array();

$total = count($request->path_scan_ijazah);
// return $total;

if($files=$request->file('path_scan_ijazah')){
  for ($i=0; $i < $total; $i++) { 
    $nip[] = $request->nip;
    $instansi[] = $request['nama_instansi_pendidikan'][$i];
    $jurusan[] = $request['nama_jurusan'][$i];
    $jenjang[] = $request['jenjang_pendidikan'][$i];
    $gelar[] = $request['gelar'][$i];
    $thn_masuk = $request['tahun_masuk'][$i];
    $thn_lulus = $request['tahun_lulus'][$i];
    $path = $request['path_scan_ijazah'][$i]->store('public/upload/ijazah');
    $images[] = $path;

    $data[] = Education::insert([
      'nip_employee' => $nip,
      'nama_instansi_pendidikan' => $instansi,
      'nama_jurusan' => $jurusan,
      'jenjang_pendidikan' => $jenjang,
      'gelar' => $gelar,
      'tahun_masuk' => $thn_masuk,
      'tahun_lulus' => $thn_lulus,
      'path_scan_ijazah' => $images
    ]);
  }
  // dd($data);
}
```

Please help me, what should I do?

Comment: I think you need to add```json_encode($images)``` to the ```'path_scan_ijazah'```

Comment: thanks for comment, i was try but it still not working.

Comment: Honestly, are u really want to add those arrays to their field, or you want to put them in array first. and then insert out of the loop. If you really want to put them in the loop. I think you need to convert those arrays to json by ```json_encode()```